# Tomcat Not reading Spring-Boot Application Properties

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm fairly new to spring/java and have been checking out spring-boot for a project I have at work. I've been following guides and finally have a (semi) working web app MVC + JPA for data access. Everything works when I deploy the app via the Jar method :

```
java -jar build/libs/client.jar
```

However, our application is eventually going to be deployed to Tomcat (v7.0.40) so I need to create a war file from the project.  I've followed the [converting jars to war](http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/)'s guide on the spring.io site and have run into a problem.  It appears that it is not loading up the application.properties file.  Here are the important code snippets:

src/main/java/hello/GreetingController:

```
@Controller
@Configuration
public class GreetingController {
    @Value("${app.username}")
    private String username;

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        model.addAttribute("username", username);
        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

src/main/java/hello/Application.java

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

src/main/java/hello/HelloWebXml.java

```
public class HelloWebXml extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
app.username=foo
```

for completeness, here is the build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:0.5.0.M6")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'client'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:0.5.0.M6")
    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring3:2.0.16")
    testCompile("junit:junit:4.11")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.8'
}
```

I build the application:

```
gradle clean build
```

Drop the war in tomcat, and then tail out the logs and see the following:

```
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]
.StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/client]]
...
...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating the bean
with name 'greetingController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception
is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.username' in string
value "${app.username}"
...
...
...
```

As I said, it works when I run it via a jar, but does not work when I deploy it to Tomcat.  I also looked inside `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/client/WEB-INF/classes` and I see the `application.properties` file. So I think that it should be on the classpath.  My question is, why isn't tomcat loading it? I've tried searching all over and no one else seems to be having this problem so I'm not sure if its just something I have incorrectly configured, or what.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring boot should load `application.properties` by default. Try adding `@PropertySource("application.properties")` to your `@Configuration` class to see if it actually finds it.

Comment: Hey @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, this did not work either. I got a FileNotFoundException when tomcat tried to load up the war. I can give you more details if necessary, just let me know.

Comment: Sorry, it should actually be `classpath:application.properties`

Comment: Thanks again, I went ahead and added that, but noticed a compiler warning: `Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'Repeatable': class file for java.lang.annotation.Repeatable not found.`

When I dropped it in tomcat, I got:
`Failed to load bean class: hello.Application; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Unable to collect imports; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.annotation.Repeatable`

Comment: You should post it. The full thing would be `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter on accident before I was done editing.

Comment: That's a completely unrelated class. I have no idea where that comes from.

Comment: The `Repeatable` thing is a Java 8 feature isn't it? Are you compiling on Java 8 and running of Java 7 or something?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the `@PropertySource` annotation can be used with a Spring Boot application but you don't need to declare it if it is `classpath:application.properties` (and there are some framework features that can't be configured with `@PropertySource`) - not relevant here though.

Comment: @L-Jones9 it works for me. How were you running the app (deployed WAR or on the command line, and if so how)?

Comment: @DaveSyer I am not compiling on Java 8, everything is Java 7. I was running the app by deploying my war to tomcat/webapps/client.war and then running tomcat/bin/startup.sh. So the default ways (as far as I know) to deploy a web application.

Comment: Issue [SPR-11086](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11086) looks the same as your problem with `Repeatable` and it says it was resolved in Spring 4.0 RC2, so what version are you using? But you shouldn't need to use `@PropertySource` in which case it wouldn't arise. Do you get the same problem with snapshots of Spring Boot (and M7 is staged if you want to try that)?

Comment: @DaveSyer thanks for looking into that. Yeah, it appears that I'm on RC1 and need to upgrade to RC2 which I would like to do. I'm unsure if I get the problem with the snapshots/M7 version of Spring Boot. I will have to try it when I get home tonight and let you know.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

follow this guys advice: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/how-to-propertysource-annotations-in.html

try:

```
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})
```

then boom sauce for the win.

Comment: Along with some of the comments from above, this eventually worked for me.  The question I have is still, why didn't it load the properties in the first place? In addition, adding this to my controller file gave me a compiler warning that I haven't quite figured out yet.

Comment: Repeating my comment above: this is not necessary in a Spring Boot application.

Comment: This leads to a rather peculiar error:
"ClassCastException: PropertySource cannot be cast to java.util.Map"
 while using Spring Boot on Java 7

Comment: @MikeAdler this answer refers to `PropertySources` which is plural, not `PropertySource` which is singular

Comment: Thank you ! This is ok but do you know how to load `application-xxx.properties` file from other modules ?

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you attempt to use a `@Value` annotation inside your `@Configuration` class. From the JavaDoc of the [@PropertySource](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html):

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in <bean> definitions or @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This happens automatically when using <context:property-placeholder> in XML, but must be explicitly registered using a static @Bean method when using @Configuration classes.

e.g. add the following lines to the `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

---

However, in your example, a more suitable approach is to move the `@Configuration` annotation from the `GreetingController` class (it does not contain any configuration) to the `Application` class. Since the `Application` class does not contain any `@Value` annotation it should work without the suggested addition of the static `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean.

Answer (score 0):

I came here searching for the same issue. application.properties not loading when spring boot application run as a war inside tomcat but it was working fine when running with embedded tomcat. the issue turned out to be in the file name . I had used Application.properties instead of application.properties . when running from tomcat it looks like it is case sensitive . Putting it here so that if someone commits the same stupid mistake as i did

> 2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.xml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.properties' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yaml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./application.xml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./application.yml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./application.properties' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'file:./application.yaml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.xml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.properties' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yaml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.xml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yml' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.properties' resource not found
>   2015-09-10 14:42:13,982 DEBUG o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yaml' resource not found

Comment: I had the same issue. But the file- Application.properties is generated by default during maven build. Thanks @janardhan I was stuck for hours

Answer (score 0):

I think for those who change default naming "application.[properties,yaml,etc]" to, for example, "service.[properties,yaml,etc]", can add this into the build.gradle task as:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = [
       'spring.config.name':'service'
    ]
}
```