# Spring Boot jdbc datasource autoconfiguration fails on standalone tomcat

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource, spring-boot

While trying to deploy and start a spring boot application on a standalone tomcat (7) instance, we ran into an issue were the autoconfigured spring datasource bean isn't found and the corresponding exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}    at
     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1060)  at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)   at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)     at 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)   ... 84 more
```

The simple jdbc spring.datasource is properly configured in the application.properties and the application itself runs perfectly with an embedded tomcat instance as a standalone spring boot application.

It seems as if the application.properties file cannot be read and/or processed properly, or the injection of some other beans (a service in a REST controller for example) is triggered before the datasource autoconfiguration has been done.

Is any extra configuration required when not using an embedded tomcat?
Or has anyone run into similar issues?

The simple application and configuration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foo")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Datasource usage example:

```
@Repository
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

...
}
```

Pom parent & dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0.M6</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.27</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RC1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Auto configuration report of failed start:

```
=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration
      - existing auto database detected (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.DatabaseCondition)
      - existing auto database detected (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.DatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration#jdbcTemplate
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.JdbcTemplateConfiguration#namedParameterJdbcTemplate
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatConfiguration
      - found database driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatDatabaseCondition)
      - found database driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.TomcatDatabaseCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration#transactionManager
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [dataSource] @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: transactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [dataSource] @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: transactionManager; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory] (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration#dispatcherServlet
      - no DispatcherServlet found (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration#serverProperties
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   RabbitAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect,org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice (OnClassCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.mongodb.Mongo,org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.DbcpConfiguration
      - tomcat DataSource (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.BasicDatabaseCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedConfiguration
      - existing non-embedded database detected (DataSourceAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedDatabaseCondition)

   JmsTemplateAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate,javax.jms.ConnectionFactory (OnClassCondition)

   DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor,org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: javax.persistence.EntityManager,org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager (OnClassCondition)

   ReactorAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: reactor.spring.context.config.EnableReactor (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server,org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader (OnClassCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#beanNameViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler (OnClassCondition)
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you included something like <util:properties id="props" location="classpath:application.properties" /> in your application context. And could you tell where exactly have you placed the application.properties. It should typically be there somewhere like src/main/resources

Comment: spring-boot autoconfiguration should make explictly importing properties obsolete (and the application works fine when i run it standalone) and application.properties is indeed in src/main/resources folder

Comment: Please post your configuration files as well. That would make it much easier to figure it out!

Comment: most (if not all) configuration is set up by spring boot through autoconfiguration and component scanning. The datasource is autowired in an example repository above.

Comment: Could you post the dependencies added in your pom and the output of the autoconfiguration done by boot?

Comment: added dependencies and output to the question

Comment: It works for me. Can you share the code e.g. on github?

Comment: I'll try to set up an example project containing the problem somewhere this week. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Hi Dave, could this be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667653/tomcat-not-reading-spring-boot-application-properties ?

Comment: I've added an example project on github, that has the same NoSuchBeanException after deploying the war to tomcat and starting the application. (the spring datasource properties are dummies in the example, but that shouldn't matter for this example).

Comment: Ow, and the url :-) https://github.com/vandammeb/spring-boot-example

Comment: Same error with 0.5.0.M6 and Tomcat 7.0.42. Seems to work with the 0.5.0.M7 version and Tomcat 7.0.47 though.

Comment: where is your datasource defintion? I think this error means Spring cannot find bean named "dataSource" for  MyRepositoryImpl.

Comment: @Jason Spring Boot creates the datasource automatically based on the property names. There is no need to define the datasource manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely an issue with the 0.5.0.M6 version and the Tomcat version you are using. It does work with Spring Boot 0.5.0.M7 and Tomcat 7.0.47.

Comment: can yo  reply to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967143/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-javax-sql-datasource-is-defined. Its same think but I am getting where is the issue ?

Answer (score 7):

Hi make sure you are not missing the JPA library.

> spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Answer (score 6):

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Worked for me for version 1.3.3

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue earlier and same was resolved by adding

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

in Application.java
Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

For me it was throwing the exception in JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration. I added exclude JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration in the Application.java.
Hope it helps.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class })
```