# Spring Boot - Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connectivity

I have Spring Boot web application. It's centered around RESTful approach. All configuration seems in place but for some reason MainController fails to handle request. It results in 404 error. How to fix it?

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    ParserService parserService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String displayStartPage(){
        return "{hello}";
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
        public static void main(final String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }
}
```

**ParserController**

```
@RestController
public class ParserController {

    @Autowired
    private ParserService parserService;

    @Autowired
    private RecordDao recordDao;

 private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ParserController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String fileUploadPage(
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Seems like MySQL cannot be initialized by Spring....

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()] threw exception; 

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

**UPDATE2**

**application.properties**

```yml
    # Database 
    spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/logparser
    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = root
    
    spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
    spring.jpa.show-sql = true
    
    # Hibernate
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    hibernate.show_sql: true
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
    entitymanager.packagesToScan: /
```

**UPDATE4**

Seems lite controllers not responding eventhough `@RequestMapping` are set. Why might it be?

> PS. It occurs when I run Maven's lifecycle `test`.
> When running in degub mode in IntelliJ there is no error outputted.

**UPDATE5**

Also I use this DAO as explained in tutorial....

```
public interface RecordDao extends CrudRepository<Record, Long> {
}
```

http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/

**UPDATE6**

I did changed my application properties. And tried every single combination but it refuses to work. ;(

**Maven output:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running IntegrationTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.365 sec <<< FAILURE! - in IntegrationTest
saveParsedRecordsToDatabase(IntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 2.01 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:101)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

Comment: Can you add the databse configuration?

Comment: you are mixing yaml and properties together. `hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` would be `hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`

Comment: Changed as you suggested but error persists

Comment: It looks like a classpath problem. What kind of dependency do you have for your database, and how is it defined in the pom.xml (e.g. which scope etc.). Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Try removing @Transactional from UserDao

Comment: In my case it was [spring-boot-starter-data-jpa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37554576/234110)

Comment: In my case, I was using `PostgreSQL` but was still using the `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432/mystore` where I should have used `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mystore`. Posting in hopes that I'm not the lone kind out here.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Looks like the initial problem is with the auto-config.

If you don't need the datasource, simply remove it from the auto-config process:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Edit:
If using @SpringBootApplication in your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: I am new to this... is it common to everyone -the DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by common....
The DataSourceAutoConfiguration is a mechanism to create and load datasource configuration. Properties with the 'spring.datasource' prefix are loaded into the DataSourceProperties bean/object
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html or 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration.html

Comment: And I suppose another valid answer whould have been to add the 'spring.datasource.*'  properties.

Comment: newer spring boot version: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: Or add yaml property: ```spring.datasource.initialize: false```

Answer (score 42):

Maybe you forgot the MySQL JDBC driver.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 40):

From the looks of things you haven't passed enough data to Spring Boot to configure the datasource

Create/In your existing `application.properties` add the following

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

making sure you append a value for each of properties.

Comment: I already have that file and config, although it slightly different `spring.datasource.driver-class-name` instead of your `spring.datasource.driverClassName`

Comment: and if you change the config for `driver-class-name` to `driverClassName`, does it work or a different error?

Comment: @J.Olufsen I think `driverClassName` changed to `type`

Answer (score 12):

I am working with spring boot 2.6.0
I tried several answers and they were not enough.
One temporal solution I found was this

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SqlInitializationAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Although it lets the server run and the h2-console appear I could not connect to my data.sql file. This was the error I got

```
Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149
```

This is the solution I found
(Some have already been)Add these lines to the application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Save an re-run the server then try to access the db on the browser again from the h2-console

By default, data.sql scripts are now run before Hibernate is initialized. This aligns the behavior of basic script-based initialization with that of Flyway and Liquibase. If you want to use data.sql to populate a schema created by Hibernate, set spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true.

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true solves the issue

Answer (score 8):

I was getting the same error, found out it was due to some of the dependencies missing in my pom.xml like that of Spring JPA, Hibernate, Mysql or maybe Jackson.
So make sure that dependencies are not missing in your pom.xml and check their version compatibility.

```
<!-- Jpa and hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

writing the above line in application.properties , it worked for me in case psql db with spring boot 3.0.3

Answer (score 5):

change below line of code

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName
```

to

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name
```

Comment: and added before spring.datasource.type

Comment: application.yml dont care if its camel case or dash-case

Answer (score 5):

This problem comes while you are running Test.
Add dependency

```
testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.197'
```

Add folder resources under test source add file bootstrap.yml
and provide content.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:TEST
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: username
    password: password
    hikari:
      idle-timeout: 10000
```

this will setup your data source.

Answer (score 4):

The `hibernate.*` properties are useless, they should be `spring.jpa.*` properties. Not to mention that you are trying to override those already set by using the `spring.jpa.*` properties. (For the explanation of each property I strongly suggest a read of the Spring Boot [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jpa-and-spring-data).

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Also the packages to scan are automatically detected based on the base package of your `Application` class. If you want to specify something else use the `@EntityScan` annotation. Also specifying the most toplevel package isn't really wise as it will scan the whole class path which will severely impact performance.

Comment: Although I changed properties as you suggested same error. Controllers not working (`404 error`) as well

Comment: Your question is deviating from the original one... That a controller cannot be found has nothing to do with a datasource. I would suggest marking the answer that solved your datasource problem and issue a new one for the controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Check that you have database dependency at **runtime** group at build.gradle

```
runtime group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.194'
```

or change scope from test to **runtime** if you use Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.194</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using application.properties in spring boot app, then just put the below line into application.properties and it should work:
**spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://google/?cloudSqlInstance=&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=****&password=******

Answer (score 2):

Not directly related to the original question but this will be useful for someone. This error occurred to me with a simple two project structure. One project was handling some database operations with spring JDBC (say A) and the other did not have any JDBC operations at all(say B). But still, this error appeared while I was starting service B. Saying the datasource should be initialized properly.

As I figured out I had added this dependency to the parent pom of the two modules

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This caused spring to initialize the JDBC dependencies for project B too. So, I moved it to project A's pom, everything was fine.

Hope this would help someone

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are having a problem with datasource.
If you don't need the datasource, simply disable it using

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Just put this in your application.properties

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot version 2+ has a minor change. All DDL(Data Definition Language) - Table Creations and data updates should be done in **schema.sql**

To resolve this issue just add this

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
```

to application.properties file.

or

```
spring:
  jpa:
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

Add the above if you using yml to your application.yml file.

**For Example for H2 In Memory Configuration**

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization = true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:todo
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

Sometimes I've got a SQL Syntax Error when executing the spring boot application because of forgetting the **semicolon(;)** at the end of CREATE TABLE and sometimes **SYSDATE()** and **NOW()** have problems using **NOW()** for the current date, so make sure to write the correct SQL syntax for DDL or DML

Answer (score 2):

In the current context(above JDK17 & above Springboot 2.7), this issue commonly occurred. There are reasons for this connectivity issue. But common thing I have noticed when it occurred to me is clearly a connectivity issue related to databaseAutoConfiguration. The main database may be connected successfully with its properties and the test db doesnt. So need to build the project again to trigger the connection from the application.properties manually.

The error log of my particular scenario.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoConfigureTestDatabase.

So the solution that I'm proposing are

1. Check the connector dependencies
2. Check the application properties and the input credentials.
3. Make sure the build the project by triggering the maven or gradle manually.
4. Don't trust the autoconfiguration part and investigate it deeply.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was happening because org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource is an autowired field without a Qualifier and I am using multiple datasources with qualified names.  I solved this problem by using @Primary arbitrarily on one of my dataSource bean configurations like so

```
@Primary
@Bean(name="oneOfManyDataSources")
public DataSource dataSource() { ... }
```

I suppose they want you to implement AbstractRoutingDataSource, and then that auto configuration will just work because no qualifier is needed, you just have a single data source that allows your beans to resolve to the appropriate DataSource as needed.  Then you don't need the @Primary or @Qualifier annotations at all, because you just have a single DataSource.

In any case, my solution worked because my beans specify DataSource by qualifier, and the JPA auto config stuff is happy because it has a single primary DataSource.  I am by no means recommending this as the "right" way to do things, but in my case it solved the problem quickly and did not deter the behavior of my application in any noticeable manner.  Will hopefully one day get around to implementing the AbstractRoutingDataSource and refactoring all the beans that need a specific DataSource and then perhaps that will be a neater solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue even after supplying all required datasource properties in application.properties. Then I realized that properties configuration class was not getting scanned by Spring boot because it was in different package hierarchy compared to my Spring boot Application.java and hence no properties were applied to datasource object. 
I changed the package name of my properties configuration class and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just ignored the following in application.properties file:

# Hibernate

#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

It works for me....

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem for several days, and finally the issue isn't with the code, the problem commes from maven, you must delete all the files that he downloaded from your hard drive "C:\Users\username.m2\repository", and do another update maven for your project, that will fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

By default, with the latest version of Spring Boot, the load of data.sql is done before the tables are created. So use - spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

Example -

```
**In application.properties :- **
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Thanks
Athar Karim

Comment: I encountered the same issue with H2 as my database for a Spring boot app I'm working on. After doing some research, adding this `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true` configuration to application.properties file solved my problem.

You have same explanation as with this https://roytuts.com/integrate-h2-in-memory-database-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had inserted a record in a table in `data.sql`, but that table's name was incorrect in `schema.sql`, where I had created that table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the application as a jar? ( java -jar xxxx.jar)

If so, do you have the application.properties stored in that jar ?

If no, try to figure out why :

- To be automatically package in the jar, the files can be in : src/main/resources/application.properties
- The maven plugin in the pom.xml can also be configured

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me you can try your:
Add this to VM options in Tomcat

```
-DdevBaseDir="C:\Your_Project_Dir_Path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give you something different, when you encounter this kind of error, cannot create 
bean datasource in a test case.

It might be caused by some reasons:

1. No datasource, you will need to create your datasource, h2 in-memory datasource or whatever, or you can choose the way like `exclude={datasource··}`.
2. You have your datasource, like MySQL, but it still not work. It was caused by class `AutoConfigureTestDatabase`, It will choose a datasource for you which may cause ambiguity.

Solution: add `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` to avoid replace the default datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the change of the parent Spring Boot Dependency.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

to

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

For more Information, take a look at the release notes: [Spring Boot 2.1.0 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes)

Answer (score 0):

**Created database in MySQL**

```
create database springboot2;
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot2
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
server.port=9192
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**main class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**model class**

```
package com.First.Try.springboot.entity;
    
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_TBL1")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    ....
    ....
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql you need 2 dependencies

1

```
. <dependency>          
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>        </dependency>
```

2. 

```
 <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>   </dependency>
```

If you are using potgress you only need :

1.

```
<dependency>        
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>              
      <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

using h2  and you need to add  data.sql  just make sure you  add

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

on the application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
```

I'm using IntelliJ community edition with DB Browser Plugin

It works for me...

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue give the primary key column value  @NotNull not NULL annotation and it would work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Please add the below dependency to get rid of this.

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you add all the dependencies in your pom.xml

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me no need to update below `@SpringBootApplication` annotation as `@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})`

Just updated deprecated `spring.datasource.platform=h2` into `spring.sql.init.platform=h2` and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this issue in gradle, you need to remove the Spring data library and rebuild gradle. I had to remove the following dependency to solve the error

```
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
```

Answer (score -1):

I have not used h2 configuration in pom file.I have added it and this problem was solved.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```