# Spring Boot Test "Failed to load ApplicationContext"

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am getting an error while testing my rest application but can't understand why.My error output:

> ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext  at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
> at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
> at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)  at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)  at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'
> defined in class path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to
> replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an
> embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune
> the replace attribute of @AutoConfigureTestDatabase.

While I try to do this test:

```
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SaveServiceTest {

@Autowired
private MedsRepo medsRepo;

@Test
void testSaveMeds() {
    Meds meds = new Meds(50, "test med", "5,00$", "Flu", 500, "test date");
    Meds savedMed = medsRepo.save(meds);
    assertThat(savedMed).usingRecursiveComparison().ignoringFields("id").isEqualTo("meds");

}
}
```

My saveMeds() :

```
@Service
public class SaveService {

@Autowired
private MedsRepo medsRepo;

public String saveMeds(@RequestBody Meds meds) {

    medsRepo.save(meds);

    return "Saved Successfully";

 }
 }
```

My repository:

```
 public interface MedsRepo extends JpaRepository<Meds,Long> {

 }
```

and Meds :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Meds {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
private long id;//no need for long instead of int

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String price; //ask if not used in operations

@Column
private String category;

@Column
private int pillNumber; 

@Column
private String date;

}´´´
```

The error stops the test in the line:

````
I do not understand the problem. I call the SaveService in a controller:

 ``` @RestController
  public class Controller {

  @Autowired
  private MedsRepo medsRepo;

  @Autowired
  private SaveService saveService;

  @Autowired
  private UpdateService updateService;

  @Autowired 
  DeleteService deleteService;
      

  @GetMapping("/medicines")
  public List<Meds> getMedicine(){

      return medsRepo.findAll();

  }

  @PostMapping(value = "/save")
  public String saveMeds(@RequestBody Meds meds){

      return saveService.saveMeds(meds);
  }

  @PutMapping(value = "/update/{id}")
  public String updateMeds(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Meds meds){
      

      return updateService.updateMeds(id, meds);
  }

  @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
  public String deleteMeds(@PathVariable long id){
      
      return deleteService.deleteMeds(id);
  }
  
  }´´´
````

Comment: Your database for test, have a look at the end of the log.

Comment: @Bernardo Alves Hi, I am facing a similar one ? Can you please share what worked for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't to use request body annotation in service, we use it in controller.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate: [Spring Boot - Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042426/spring-boot-error-creating-bean-with-name-datasource-defined-in-class-path-r)

Spring boot is trying to load an inject dependencies in this spring class when you run your tests:

org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class

Either you provide all necessary configuration for this class in application-test.properties (or application-test.yml, if it's your case) or you disable this class from loading like mentioned in the link above.