# Spring Boot does not load application.properties and Velocity templates

Tags: spring-boot

I have two projects - one is based on the ["get started" example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/), second is from the [spring-boot-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-velocity). I build both with Maven and run both from Eclipse. The "spring-boot-samples" project loads application.properties and displays Velocity templates named by the Controller. The "get started" does not.

Same file structure for application.properties (src/main/resources/application.properties) and templates (src/main/resources/templates/**), both with src/main/resources set to "Use as Source Folder" in Eclipse. Same workspace, same JRE.

I compared the .classpath and pom.xml, but found nothing suspicious. Obviously there's a difference, but where do I have to look?

PS: I can load application.properties via [@PropertySources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683140/3890673), but

- that should not be neccessary (see comments there)
- *is* not necessary in the "spring-boot-samples" project
- does not help concerning the Velocity templates

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, one important difference:

@RestController delivers the response directly, meaning: Instead of resolving the template's name the String is passed to the browser. The reason should be [@ResponseBody:](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html)

> Annotation that indicates a method return value should be bound to the web response body.

Using @Controller instead solves the Velocity problem.

EDIT:

To close this thread: I will continue using @PropertySources to get application.properties, but it does not work without it. Just having application.properties in your classpath is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch values from application.properties in spring boot, we need to specify some annotation.

- application.properties must be in the path src/main/resources
- class must contain @RestController annotation

  @Value("${name}")
  private String name;

Comment: - application.properties is located under src/main/resources (see question text)
 - Annotation ist set
 - @Value is null all the time

I double checked if application.properties is loaded by adding some invalid information to it. Result: Parsing exception if application.properties is included via \@PropertySources, NO exception if trying to load automatically...