# Spring-boot @Value binding Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Facing a weird issue with spring-boot property-resolver.

Trying to do a simple @Value for one of the properties. In the debug log, i see the property being matched,, but reporting it as unable to find a few lines later. Any idea on what's going wrong?

Java code:

```
@Configuration
public class TestAppConfig{

    @Value("${appName}")
    private String applicationName;
}
```

Log below

```
10 Jun 2015 18:41:42 org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver DEBUG {Searching for key 'appName' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/config/application-dev.yml]]}
10 Jun 2015 18:41:42 org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver DEBUG {Searching for key 'appName' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/config/application.yml]]}
10 Jun 2015 18:41:42 org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver DEBUG {Found key 'appName' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/config/application.yml]] with type [String] and value 'testApp'}

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'appName' in string value "${appName}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you deployed your app as war inside a web container but you need to confirm. You need to add the method below to your class. Look at a related [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667653/tomcat-not-reading-spring-boot-application-properties/23047364#23047364)

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Comment: There was a duplicate PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer definition in one of the xml config causing this issue. Thanks! This was occuring in both WAR mode & Boot-mode(mvn spring-boot:run)