# Sprint boot application could not be deployed in external vm. Throws HTTP 404 when I tried loading the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, tomcat8

I deployed the spring boot application in external vm in tomcat 8. But, when I tried loading the same. I throws HTTP 404 (resource not available) . Below is the content of catalina.out file

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.controller.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]
```

What can I do to resolve this. I am new to spring boot. Please help. Adding application.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;



@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.abc")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.abc.repository")
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@EntityScan("com.abc.pojo")

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Autowired
private LdapDAO ldapDao;

@Autowired
private HoursService hoursService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);         
    }   

}
```

Thanks,
Poorna.

Comment: Looks like you `application.properties` file not included into the build. Check it please.

Comment: Application.properties file is already present inside the classes folder of web-inf.

Comment: Post you class `com.altair.dlc.controller.Application`.

Comment: added the code as part of the question itself.Please have a look.

Comment: Try to add `@SpringBootApplication` annotation to your class.

Comment: So your application is deployed as a war and not an executable jar with embedded Tomcat?

Comment: I added @SpringBootApplication and gave a try. But it is not working again.

Answer (score 0):

Poorna,

Based on the load order and location specified by SpringBoot:

> Spring Boot resolves external configuration file such as "application.properties" or "application.yml" in following order:
>
> classpath root
>
> current directory
>
> **classpath /config package**
>
> /config subdir of the current directory.

Based on this information, your application.properties file should be in a /config directory within your classpath. So, if you are placing it in WEB-INF/classes, which would be part of the classpath, it should be moved to:

/WEB-INF/classes/config/application.properties.

Additionally, if that didn't solve your problem, check the `@PropertySource` tag. Since you expect application.properties to be loaded via the classpath, it is common to prepend 'classpath: to the location, as in:

`@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`

That should  work, but in case it doesn't try adding the 'config' path in from of the file name:

`@PropertySource("classpath:config/application.properties")`

It also appears there is some relevant information here: [Tomcat Not reading Spring-Boot Application Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667653/tomcat-not-reading-spring-boot-application-properties). The most relevant point besides what I have already described is that Tomcat can be case sensitive.

Make sure your properties files is named: **application.properties** and *not* Application.properties

Comment: I tried this as well. It is not working.But, this time the exception is changed. It is able to read application.properties file.I am getting the below error :  Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I got it working by creating db in the vm. But, none of the controller mappings are working, I just get to see the static html pagfes. Any idea?